# How to run service executor from Swing worker?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker

I'm writing an IP scanner application and the process is taking long time so what i used at back scene of **gui** is service executor like:

```
 public static List<Future<String>> checkThisIP(String ipStart, String ipEnd) throws UnknownHostException {
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    final List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    String ipStringStart;
    String ipStringEnd;
    String targetIpString;
    //my update
    ipStringStart = ipStart.substring(ipStart.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, ipStart.length());
    ipStringEnd = ipEnd.substring(ipEnd.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, ipEnd.length());
    targetIpString = ipStart.substring(0, ipStart.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    if (!ipStart.equals(ipEnd)) {
        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(ipStringStart); i <= Integer.parseInt(ipStringEnd); i++) {
            String currentIp = targetIpString + i;
            futures.add(runPingScan(es, currentIp));
        }
    } else {
        futures.add(runPingScan(es, ipStart));
    }
    es.shutdown();
    return futures;
}


public static Future<String> runPingScan(final ExecutorService es, final String ip) {
    return es.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() {
            String returnMe = "";
           //custom ping class 
            Ping p = new Ping();
            //send message
            p.SendReply(ip);
            //IsReachable returns ture or false
            if(p.IsReachable()){
                returnMe=ip;
            }
            return returnMe;
           }

    });
}
```

This is the original laggy code action preformed using Jbutton:

```
 // scan result is Future list returned from service executor 
    List<Future<String>> scanResult = p.checkThisIP(jFormattedTextField1.getText(), jFormattedTextField2.getText());
                    for (final Future<String> f : scanResult) {
                        try {
                            ip = f.get();
                            if (!ip.equals("")) {
                                arp ARP = new arp();
                                PortScan openPort = new PortScan();
                                IP ipClass = new IP();
                                mac = ARP.getMac(ip);
                                manufacturer = ARP.getOUI(mac);
                                ports = openPort.checkIpForPorts(ip);
                                hostname = ipClass.hostname(ip);
                                title = ipClass.htmlTitle(ip);
                                Object[] data = {ip, mac, manufacturer, ports, hostname, title};
                                tableModel.addRow(data);
                            }

                            if (jFormattedTextField1.getText().equals(jFormattedTextField2.getText()) && ip.equals("")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Can not ping the address ! <br> Server might be protected by <b>WAF</b>.</html>", "Alert", HEIGHT);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
```

Running this code is good but when i attach it to **Start Scan Button** the gui lags, I googled and figured out to use **Swing Worker**. When i implemented the swing worker alone it killed the concurrency and when i implemented both the gui still lags. My question is there anyway to make the button (Swing worker) call the service executor to do the other processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by implementing the swing worker and the function **do in back ground** will start a new thread for service executor and prevent the lag.

```
//The actionpreformed by the button
   SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
        // All actions are done this method
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                String ip = "";
                String mac = "";
                String manufacturer = "";
                String ports = "";
                String hostname = "";
                String title = "";
                tableModel.setRowCount(0);
                PingScan p = new PingScan();
                List<Future<String>> scanResult = p.checkThisIP(jFormattedTextField1.getText(), jFormattedTextField2.getText());
                for (final Future<String> f : scanResult) {
                    try {
                        ip = f.get();
                        if (!ip.equals("")) {
                            arp ARP = new arp();
                            PortScan openPort = new PortScan();
                            IP ipClass = new IP();
                            mac = ARP.getMac(ip);
                            manufacturer = ARP.getOUI(mac);
                            ports = openPort.checkIpForPorts(ip);
                            hostname = ipClass.hostname(ip);
                            title = ipClass.htmlTitle(ip);
                            Object[] data = {ip, mac, manufacturer, ports, hostname, title};
                            tableModel.addRow(data);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
     worker.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

> When i implemented the swing worker alone it killed the concurrency and when i implemented both the gui still lags.

There's two things to do here:

- spreading your ping checks over multiple threads

  - split your task into independent sub-tasks
  - run sub-tasks in a thread-pool
  - collect results
- detaching the whole operation from the event dispach thread

  - register user action (click, keypress), get data from text fields, build task
  - run task outside of the EDT
  - update the gui, showing the results

You're doing the first part with the `ExecutorService`, for some of your code. The second part is not done in your code, so the EDT will block until the whole operation is finished, making your gui lag.

You'll need to move this code to a swing worker, which runs the tasks in the executor:

```
List<Future<String>> scanResult = p.checkThisIP(jFormattedTextField1.getText(), jFormattedTextField2.getText());
                for (final Future<String> f : scanResult) {
                    try {
                        [...] // this is where the thread blocks, making your ui lag if it's the EDT
                        Object[] data = {ip, mac, manufacturer, ports, hostname, title};
```

First, move all blocking code to be handled by the executor's thread pool:

```
public static Future<Object[]> runPingScan(final ExecutorService es, final String ip) {
    return es.submit(new Callable<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public Object[] call() {
            //custom ping class 
            Ping p = new Ping();
            //send message
            p.SendReply(ip);
            //IsReachable returns ture or false
            if(p.IsReachable()){
                [...] // other blocking code
                return {ip, mac, manufacturer, ports, hostname, title};
            } else {
                // special case, use null values or throw an exception
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can use the [Simple Background Tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) tutorial code to detach the whole thing from the EDT:

```
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<List<Object[]>, Void>() {
    public List<Object[]> doInBackground() {
        // -- this will run in another thread --
        // submit ping checks to the executor
        List<Future<Object[]>> scanResult = [...]
        // get results, put them in a list, return it
        List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Future<Object[]> f : scanResult) {
            result.add(f.get()); // blocking happens here, outside of the EDT
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void done() {
        // -- this will run in the EDT --
        // get() the list created above
        // display the result in the gui
        for(Object[] data : get()) {
            tableModel.addRow(data);
        }
    }
};
```

What's not included here are special cases like a failed ping check, you'll need to handle them somehow. Every exception thrown from within your callables is rethrown when calling `f.get()`, wrapped in an `ExecutionException`. Using that for those special cases is probably your best option.

Comment: Thanks for explanation +1. Note that the Swingworker first parameter should be List<Future<String>> and i've tried your answer but i faced the same lag. Look at my answer down, I only used the swingworker function **doInBackground()** to call the functions that uses **service executor** (Lag cause) with no other swingfunction function.

Comment: The first type parameter defines tha data created by `doInBackground` which is picked up later by calling `get`. It is meant to just be a list of strings, no need for futures as all ping checks will have completed at that point. If you do everything inside `doInBackground`, make sure that your model handles the gui updates right (i.e. `invokeLater`), as Swing is not thread-safe and anything that touches it's components should do so from the EDT.

Comment: As far i know the List of string can't take List<Future<String>> . `List<Future<String>> scanResult = p.checkThisIP(ip1,ip2); // the function returns Future list ` so if we want to return that list from `doInbackground()` the first parameter should be  `<Future<String>> `.

P.S: i've tried tried it myself. Thanks !

Comment: `// get results, put them in a list, return it`. In other words: Create an empty `List<String>`, iterate over the list of futures, `f.get()` every result and put that in the new list. Loking at the rest of your code (after `if (!ip.equals("")) {`), it is probably better to move that out of the EDT and into the executor as well, as it sounds mostly io bound. I'll update my answer to include this.